# JQuery Validation plugin with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, jquery-validate

My front-end validation rules don't seem to work. Herewith my create.blade.php and member_form.blade.php files

create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($member, ['action' => 'MemberController@store', 'id' => 'createform']) !!}

    @include('members.partials.member_form')

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save Member</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#createform").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required:true
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

member_form.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('name', 'First Name:') !!}
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

When I'm testing the Jquery validation plugin, I only get my back-end validation messages. No front-end validation message appear when I try to create a blank create form where no name input is entered. Did I enter the js script in the wrong place or is my code wrong? Documentation seem to be inline with what I coded here.

Rendered HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://tomcrud.test:8080/members/store" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="createform"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Q1UhJGJBEvBKqZ2O8FuKL4ukY7Zdedfi0HUn2iHU">

        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="surname">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="surname" type="text" id="surname">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_number">ID Number:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="id_number" type="text" id="id_number">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="mobile_number" type="text" id="mobile_number">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" id="email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date_of_birth">D.O.B:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="date_of_birth" type="text" id="date_of_birth">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="language_id">Language:</label>
    <select id="language_id" name="language_id"><option value="1">Afrikaans</option><option value="2">English</option><option value="3">Dutch</option><option value="4">Swahili</option><option value="5">German</option></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="interest_id[]">Interest:</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="interest_id[]" name="interest_id[]"><option value="1">Rugby</option><option value="2">Golf</option><option value="3">Tennis</option><option value="4">Squash</option><option value="5">Paragliding</option><option value="6">Movies</option><option value="7">Hiking</option><option value="8">Diving</option><option value="9">Fishing</option><option value="10">Hunting</option></select>
</div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save Member</button>

    </form>
```

Script files:

```
<script src="http://tomcrud.test:8080/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://tomcrud.test:8080/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://tomcrud.test:8080/js/delete_confirm.js"></script>
<script src="http://tomcrud.test:8080/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot client-side code then you need to show us the **client-side** code.  In other words, where is the ***rendered*** HTML markup for the form?

Comment: Does the `input` element contain a `name` attribute?  If so, is it `name="name"`, because that's exactly how you've declared the rule and it will not work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sparky. I added the rendered html. PS - I downloaded the JQuery software and added the file to the scripts in my master file. Not sure if that might have an impact? Help appreciated

Comment: I also added the script files, but can't see anything weird there.

Comment: have you tried writing these validate rules in a function then add the form on('submit') event? It looks like this validation will activate when ever the page is loaded. you need to add it to form submit event

Comment: @Haque, that's wrong, completely wrong. The `.validate()` method is **supposed to** be called on page load in order to *initialize* the plugin. Then the the `submit` event is *automatically* captured by the plugin.

Comment: The code that you posted above is working for the `name` field:  https://jsfiddle.net/90kvqmze/ ~ please check your console for JavaScript errors.  Perhaps your files are not being included properly?

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of the day, the fix was a really stupid one. I spoke to one of my developer friends and he advised that I should place the  reference in the  and not at the bottom of the master file . That fixed it! Why though? I have no idea...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ProPay_CRUD - @yield('title')</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}">
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        @include('shared.header')

        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col justify-content-center'>
                    <p></p>
                    @include('shared.errors')
                    @include('shared.message')

                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @include('shared.footer')

        <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/delete_confirm.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/additional-methods.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/validation.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```